# Laravel 5.0: Route with query string

Tags: laravel-5, routes, query-string

I am using laravel 5.0, I am sending a query string on **A** tag with an id.
I am getting id but not the query string data

Below is the code:
**View**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="img-decor">
            <a href="{{url('buycarddetail/'.$retailer->id)}}" class="">
              <img src="{{ assetnew('uploads/client_image/'.$retailer->image) }}" alt="..." class="img-rounded" width="200">
            </a>
            <div class="deals-title">
            {{ $retailer->name }}
                <div class="sub-details">Save up to {{ $retailer->discount }}%</div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function buycarddetail($id = null, Request $request)
    {
        echo $id; 
            echo '<pre>'; $data = $request->all(); exit;
        return view('buycarddetail');

    }
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('buycarddetail/{id}', ['as' => 'buycarddetail', 'uses' => 'HomeController@buycarddetail']);
```

I want to use the query string data for further process on controller
Please help

Comment: From your code it's apparent that you're only sending the id in the url and no actual query string data. `{{url('buycarddetail/'.$retailer->id)}}`

Comment: example.com/buycarddetail/17?_token=msUCIVKokmPg5yjq2vRzlOZbbuo2zeHIDzSYhQxI&_token=msUCIVKokmPg5yjq2vRzlOZbbuo2zeHIDzSYhQxI&brand=&buybrand=+&intialsearch=&price%5B%5D=0-25

Comment: @Sandeesh thanks, above is the URL. How can i send the query string and get into controller

Comment: Check my answer. The code does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code you're not actually appending any query string when generating the link `{{url('buycarddetail/'.$retailer->id)}}`.

As per your comments you can do this to generate a link to your route with the query string.

```
{{ route('buycarddetail', ['id' => $retailer->id, '_token' => csrf_token(), 'brand' => 'test', 'buybrand' => 'example']) }}
```

This example would generate a link like

```
http://example.com/buycarddetail/17?_token=QHE8va7stXUOPabwTjKmXyJxdsuPSZ9VbH3uThwx&brand=test&buybrand=example
```